# htaccess www to non-www redirect (and config.php)

Tags: redirect, htaccess, index

I need to set up a redirect from the www version of my site to the non-www version for SEO. I found a solution that *would* work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www#answer-1270281) if it weren't for the fact that it breaks the index.php redirect that comes with craft.

Can anyone tell me how to implement a generic redirect from http://www.site.co.uk to http://site.co.uk and still keep the index.php craft redirect working?

Additionally, does this affect the config.php file, or does that get loaded AFTER the redirect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing you have the necessary permissions to do this, the following in your .htaccess should do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In place, the full file will probably look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to non-www domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The following seems to work for me as a generic option:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks Steve. Any idea how I might do it generically without using the domain name?

Comment: I've updated the above with some generic code (taken from your original post) that seems to work for me without error. Can you give it a shot and see?

Comment: Seems to be fine, thanks muchly! http://www.codeknight.co.uk/portfolio

Comment: If you are using `.htaccess` for the redirect, the redirect happens before `index.php` is called (and therefore also before `config.php` is called.)